# Visual Studio .NET 2010 Permission Failure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

Has anyone ran into a problem with a Visual Studio .NET 2010 Solution that contains a web application not loading the web application on the Windows XP SP3 Operating System?

> C:\Development\WebProjects\MyApp\web\web.csproj
>   : error : The Web Application Project
>   web is configured to use IIS. To
>   access Web sites on the local IIS Web
>   server, you must run Visual Studio
>   under an Administrator account.

I am stummped and I have tried the following:

1. Added my account to the local administrators group
2. Right clicked the web application and selected reload
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio .NET 2010
4. Browsed to the VS.NET 2010 executable, selected run as, and ran as administrator

None of the four items above worked and I ran out of ideas. In fact the information I found talks to Vista and Win7 and not XP.

Answer (score 0):

I found uninstalling IIS and re-installing as well as running aspnet_regiis.exe -ga ASPNET resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to this because this is the only thread I found online with the same issue as I had a few days ago (similarly for Visual Studio 2010 on Win XP SP3) and I took a while to figure it out.

Steps I took to resolve:

1. Reinstalled IIS.
2. IIS was then reading my .aspx files
           as XML files and giving XML parsing
           errors. I ran **aspnet_regiis.exe
           -ga aspnet** from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.
3. My pages then threw
       System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentException ("Failed to access IIS metabase")
       each time I tried to access them.
       Ran **Repair** for .NET Framework 4 Extended (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555583), and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you put something invalid into the applicationHost.config file. Check that IIS Manager is showing the websites as started.

In my case I had a duplicate serviceAutoStartProviders node.